# pip flask.script install

Tags: flask

I am trying to install flask using pip install flask.script. I am following a coding tutorial from CodeUpStart. I am getting an error that says.

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask.script (from versions):
>   No matching distribution found for flask.script

I was wondering why this is and what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

RTFM: http://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#installing-flask-script

short answer: should be `pip install Flask-Script`